# Sizing bootstrap inputs but leaving label position / size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way of making an input text box small (say, col-sm-1) but keep it's label as "full length" ?

All the examples I see on SO show to wrap the label and input with a div like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
      <label for="code">Short field but i have a reeally long title that I want on one line</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is fine, but then the label is also wrapped in this div:

[image]

If I take the `label` out of the `div`:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="code">Short field but i have a reeally long title that I want on one line</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The label is fine, but aligned to the right of the input!

[image]

I've created a fiddle to show what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/42j2rz32/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using separate rows for the input and the label:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label for="code">Short field but i have a reeally long title that I want on one line</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/EcQtj8LqFy

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="code">Short field but i have a reeally long title that I want on one line</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, I want the input underneath the label, as it was in the original example.... this seems to have the input all way over on the right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add separate them into different rows.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="code">
            Short field but i have a reeally long title that I want on one line
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```